# How to call a type that can be added / subtracted / divided / multiplied?

Tags: logic, type-theory

Is there something as the quality of something that can be added? Like "addable" or "joinable".

For example, numbers can be added, sets can be added, vectors can be added. What is the name of that quality that makes them able to be "added" together ?

I would like to know also if the same exists for things that can me multiplied / divided.

Maybe that doesn't exist at all neither ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Are you familiar with the terms "group", "ring", and "field"? I think this is what you are looking for.

There are also terms for related structures - e.g. semigroup, monoid, magma for one binary operation, and semiring, skew field for two binary operations.

In general, you may be interested in the examples section of https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_structure.

Comment: Hmm. I just googled that and my mind hurt already. Maybe it's that.

Comment: It's not too bad! Do you have a single binary operation $\oplus$ which is associative - $a\oplus(b\oplus c)=(a\oplus b)\oplus c$ - and has an identity element (a zero) and inverses (like negatives)? Then congrats, you've got a group! For instance, the set of vectors in a vector space is a group, with vector addition (in fact, it's an **abelian**, or **commutative**, group - in groups we allow $a\oplus b\not=b\oplus a$).

Comment: For an example of a nonabelian (noncommutative) group, consider the set of 2-by-2 matrices (with real number entries) with nonzero determinant, with the binary operation being multiplication.

Comment: nonabelian being a⊕b=b⊕a ?

Comment: @Ludo Nonabelian means we *don't* always have $a\oplus b=b\oplus a$.

Comment: A group is a set with one binary operation (satisfying the properties I said above - associativity, plus identity and inverses). For instance, the functions $f(a, b)=a+b$ and $g(a, b)=a+b-1$ each work on $\mathbb{R}$ - for $g$, the identity is $1$, and the inverse of $a$ is $2-a$. So $(\mathbb{R}; f)$ and $(\mathbb{R}; g)$ are each groups. But $(\mathbb{R}; f, g)$ is not a group, since it has two binary operations instead of one. A set may have many ways of being turned into a group, but each group has only one binary operation.

Comment: Oh I see. A group is the combination of the operation AND the set.

Comment: @Ludo Exactly. By the way, usually a group arises in the context of a **group action** - elements of the group are interpreted as transformations of some other object. The usual word tossed around here is "symmetries" - for instance, an equilateral triangle has six symmetries, and they form a group under composition (the binary operation is "do one, then the other"). This action isn't strictly part of the definition, but it's how you tend to find examples - anytime you have a Thing that you're doing Stuff to, and you can always undo the Stuff you did, the Stuff is a group under composition.

Comment: I love the way you just explained all of this to me. It's just perfectly understandable. Are you a teacher? Because 5 minutes ago I was asking how to call something that can be added, now I'm understanding a nonabelian group under composition. Which blows my mind. Thank you.

Comment: Formally, a group action looks a lot like scalar multiplication - you have a group $(G, *)$ and a set $X$, and a map $G\times X\rightarrow X$ (denoted "$g\cdot x$"), such that $(g*h)\cdot x=g\cdot (h\cdot x)$ and $e\cdot x=x$ when $e$ is the identity element. There are lots of ways a group can act on a set - for example, the trivial action $g\cdot x=x$ for all $g$ and $x$ is perfectly allowed!

Comment: Hehe, thanks a lot - I try!

Comment: What's the 'h' ?

Comment: $h$ is some other element of the group $G$.

Comment: The identity element in the integer set being 1 !!

Comment: Can that group theory be applicable to sets as well ? Like the Group being composed of the set of all sets of integers, and the operation of set union for example ?

Comment: @Ludo Yes - union doesn't work (no inverses), but **symmetric difference** does. Groups whose elements are themselves complicated sets are really important - for instance, the **Brauer group** is a group whose elements are sets of rings!